# Scala: Inherited enum object doesn't satisfy parent trait

Tags: scala, types

I am trying to use an Enumeration object in a method. The enum object extends from a trait, and the method takes the trait as a parameter. Here is the sample code.

```
sealed trait canAdd
object DAdder extends Enumeration with canAdd
{
    type DAdder = Value
    val  P, Q = Value
}

class ClassTypeTest extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers
{
    class AClass
    {
        def add(v: canAdd) = if(v.isInstanceOf[DAdder]) println("Got DAdder") else println("Got IAdder")
        def note(v: canAdd) = println("Got some canAdd trait object")
    }
    val aobj = new AClass
    val aseq: Seq[DAdder] = Seq(DAdder.P, DAdder.Q, DAdder.P)
    //*** Error in below line *****    
    aseq.foreach(aobj.add(_))
}
```

The compiler gives the following error:

```
Error:(23, 23) type mismatch;
 found   : x.x.DAdder.DAdder
    (which expands to)  x.x.DAdder.Value
 required: x.x.canAdd
    aseq.map(aobj.add(_))
```

Shouldn't I be able to pass an object that inherits the trait in a method that takes the trait as an argument? How do I fix this?

Comment: The `DAdder` object itself is a `CanAdd` but elements of the enumeration are not.

Comment: Use `enumeratum` to achieve what you intent, enumeration is limited and discouraged.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I checked this out - looks good. Can you please put this as a response? I will accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enumeration` class doesn't allow you to extends its values functionality. It is basically:

```
abstract class Enumeratum {
  sealed trait Value { /* utilities */ }
  object Value { /* factory of Values */ }
 
  // utilities
}
```

Since you have the control only on `Enumeratum` class you cannot extend `Value`s which is what you ask for.

You can easily have this functionality with `sealed trait`s and `case object`s

```
sealed trait DAdder extends canadd
object DAdder {

  case object P extends DAdder
  case object Q extends DAdder
}
```

This however misses some utilities like finding value by its name, listing all values, etc.

This problem is solved by Enumeratum library which require that you mix in some traits and cope paste one line (`val values = findValues`) to have all functionalities of Enumeration and more

```
import enumeratum._

sealed trait DAdder extends canadd
  with EnumEntry // mixin here
object DAdder extends Enum[DAdder] { // and mixin here

  case object P extends DAdder
  case object Q extends DAdder

  val values = findValues // and one line calling macro
}
```

(There are also specializations for enums that should store some primitives/strings as their values in `enumeratum.values._`).

In Scala 3 this will probably look slightly different as it introduced `enum` keyword

```
sealed trait DAdder extends canadd
object DAdder {

  case object P extends DAdder
  case object Q extends DAdder
}
```

will become

```
enum DAdder extends canadd {
  case P, Q
}
```

Scala 3's enum will `ordinal` method defined, so libraries like Enumeratum will have to provide a little fewer functionalities. (I guess  by mixing in Java's Enum trait you will have access to `values` so everything else is a matter of extension methods).